# what this error in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to fire below query on tm_matrix but gives me following error

```
mysql> INSERT INTO tm_matrix (VDT,VID)VALUES(replace(left(now(),10),'-',''),(SE
LECT CASE WHEN MAX(VID) IS NULL THEN 000001 ELSE (MAX(VID)+1) END AS VID FROM tm
_matrix));
```

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'tm_matrix' for update in FROM clause

If I fire below query then gives me following error

```
mysql> INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID)VALUES(replace(left(now(),10),'-',''),SEL
ECT CASE WHEN MAX(VID) IS NULL THEN 000001 ELSE (MAX(VID)+1) END AS VID FROM tm_
visitor);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>       corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELEC
>       T CASE WHEN MAX(VID) IS NULL THEN 000001 ELSE (MAX(VID)+1) END AS VID FROM ' at
>       line 1

If I use below query then it gives me below error

```
mysql> INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID)VALUES(replace(left(now(),10),'-',''),(SE
LECT CASE WHEN MAX(VID) IS NULL THEN 000001 ELSE (MAX(VID)+1) END AS VID));
```

ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'VID' in 'field list'

UPDATE

I tried following

```
INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID,NAME,CONTACT) SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001),6,'0') FROM tm_visitor
```

then here how can I pass value for NAME,CONTACT because here we are not using values() for inserting

Comment: The second error says: You have a space in your "SELECT" keyword ("SELEC  T"). Correct it and try again

Comment: You can not select the same table for insert/update as a Values (to be passed in the query)

Comment: @dadu That's probably just a copy-pasting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one -

```
INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID)
 SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001) FROM tm_visitor;
```

Comment: Devart: It worked but VID insert as 1,2,3 etc where I want to insert as 00001,00002,00003 etc.

Comment: Try ZEROFILL option in CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Try LPAD( COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001), 6, '0') in your select

Comment: dadu: it worked but if want to insert values into more colunms then?

Comment: dadu: it worked but if I want to insert values into more colunms then? I tried following (VDT,VID,NAME,CONTACT) SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001) FROM tm_visitor then here how can I pass value for NAME,CONTACT because here we are not using values() for inserting

Comment: dadu: it worked but if I want to insert values into more colunms then? I tried following (VDT,VID,NAME,CONTACT) SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001),6,'0') FROM tm_visitor then here how can I pass value for NAME,CONTACT because here we are not using values() for inserting

Comment: @yatinbc You might try INSERT INTO tm_visitor (VDT,VID, NAME, CONTACT)
 SELECT REPLACE(LEFT(NOW(), 10), '-', ''), LPAD(COALESCE(MAX(VID) + 1, 000001), 6, '0'), 'My name 1', 'My contact 2'  FROM tm_visitor

Comment: @dadu: I tried this earlier before asking and also works fine but what happend that VID remains same everytime don't get increment by 1. so please suggest another way

Comment: @yatinbc Try to understand it, analyze SELECT query. Also: Is VID a string? Why do not you use int data type with ZEROFILL option? Why do not you use AUTO_INCREMENT?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tm_matrix (VDT,VID)
SELECT replace(left(now(),10),'-',''), IFNULL(MAX(VID),0)+1 FROM tm_visitor
```